# Incorrect result in recursive permutation algorithm in C

Tags: c, loops, recursion

I'm the beginner of C program, so I hope that someone can give me some tips to do the questions which need the concept of recursion.

I would like to solve the following question by recursion, however I don't know where to start.

## Permutation

> ### Task Description
>
> Write a program to output all permutations of N numbers. The permutations must be outputted in sorted order according to the first number, then the second number, and so on.
>
> ### Input Format
>
> The first line of the input gives the integer N (0<N≤9). The second line contains N numbers separated in a space to be processed. The N numbers are guaranteed to be distinct.
>
> ### Output Format
>
> The output should be consisted of M lines where M is the number of different permutations of the given N numbers. Each line consists of N numbers separated by a space representing a unique permutation. Be aware of the order of those permutations.
>
> ### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4
> 30 10 20 40
> ```
>
> ### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 10 20 30 40
> 10 20 40 30
>
> 10 30 20 40
>
> 10 30 40 20
>
> 10 40 20 30
>
> 10 40 30 20
>
> 20 10 30 40
>
> 20 10 40 30
>
> 20 30 10 40
>
> 20 30 40 10
>
> 20 40 10 30
>
> 20 40 30 10
>
> 30 10 20 40
>
> 30 10 40 20
>
> 30 20 10 40
>
> 30 20 40 10
>
> 30 40 10 20
>
> 30 40 20 10
>
> 40 10 20 30
>
> 40 10 30 20
>
> 40 20 10 30
>
> 40 20 30 10
>
> 40 30 10 20
>
> 40 30 20 10
> ```

I try to solve this problem by sorting the number list first.

```
void sort(int N, int *num){
    int tmp;

    for(int i=0; i<N-1; i++){
        for(int j=i; j<N; j++){
            if(*(num+i)>*(num+j)){
                tmp = *(num+i);
                *(num+i) = *(num+j);
                *(num+j) = tmp;
            }
        }
    }   

    return;
}
```

Then I write the following code at the first place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Permutation(int start, int N, int num[N]){
    if(i>=N) return;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        if(i!=start){
            if(i == N-1){
                printf("%d\n", num[i]);
            }else{
                printf("%d ", num[i]);
            }
        }
        
        Permutation(i+1, N-i, num)
    }

    return;
}

void sort(int N, int *num){
    int tmp;

    for(int i=0; i<N-1; i++){
        for(int j=i; j<N; j++){
            if(*(num+i)>*(num+j)){
                tmp = *(num+i);
                *(num+i) = *(num+j);
                *(num+j) = tmp;
            }
        }
    }   
    return;
}

int main(){
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int num[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    sort(N, &num[0]);
    /*for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d", num[i]);
    }*/

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", num[i]);
        Permutation(i, N, num)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the logic is not correct. But I have no idea about solving this. Please give me some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to comment on your code:

In `sort()`, the declaration of the variable `tmp` does not need to be at *function scope*.
Move that into the body of the `if()`: `int tmp = *(num+i);`

The notation `*(num+i)` is better expressed as `num[i]`.
The latter is the preferred way to express the value of an element of an array.

There's no need for `return;` at the bottom of `sort()`. Less to read is appreciated by your readers.

`scanf();` returns a value (look it up!) that this code ignores. Robust code verifies the data it receives is reasonable. Suggest you add some error handling (incl. a user who wants to enter `-7` values; the dimension of your array.)

---

For brevity, the annotated code below skips over the "load and sort" operations.

```
void permute( int a[], int sz, int wrk[], int lvl ) {
    // begin with detecting the 'bottom' of the recursive calls.
    if( lvl == sz ) {
        // at the bottom, output the series from the working buffer.
        for( int i = 0; i < sz; i++ )
            printf( "%d ", wrk[i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
        return; // and start bouncing back again.
    }

    // AT THIS LEVEL, find an unused value in the original array.
    // "used" will be indicated by making the +'ve value -'ve (simple)
    for( int i = 0; i < sz; i++ )

        if( a[i] > 0 ) { // Ah-ha!!

            wrk[ lvl ] = a[i]; // copy to next available slot at this level

            a[i] *= -1; // mark this value as "used" preventing other levels from using it

            permute( a, sz, wrk, lvl + 1 ); // recursive call to next level of self

            a[i] *= -1; // unmark this value; loop and consider the next value
        }
}

int main( void ) {

    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40 }; // hard coded instead of load/sort
    int wrk[ 4 ]; // a "working" buffer to assemble next series

    permute( arr, sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0], wrk, 0 ); // level 0 to kick it off

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps you see how recursion can start, proceed, and terminate. There are alternatives to my use of -'ve values, but this is simple and effective for demonstration purposes.

Output:

```
10 20 30 40
10 20 40 30
10 30 20 40
10 30 40 20
10 40 20 30
10 40 30 20
20 10 30 40
20 10 40 30
20 30 10 40
20 30 40 10
20 40 10 30
20 40 30 10
30 10 20 40
30 10 40 20
30 20 10 40
30 20 40 10
30 40 10 20
30 40 20 10
40 10 20 30
40 10 30 20
40 20 10 30
40 20 30 10
40 30 10 20
40 30 20 10
```

Comment: I would like to know how to use `num[i]` in the function, while its value needs to change. Will those values be recorded to the original array?

Comment: Your code uses a single generic `num[ ]`... In this working demonstration, I use `arr[ ]` and `wrk[ ]`... In this example there is only **1** version of each array. (Each _level_ sees the same arrays, not copies of the original.) Changing the value of element(s) while generating permutations is not something I'd recommend. I used +/- to mark elements of `arr[ ]` as "in use"... You could use a `uint32_t` and set/clear its bits to achieve the same result.